# How to assess why git clone/fetch is so slow inside Hyper-V Server?

Tags: networking, ssh, git, hyper-v

I have git installed on Ubuntu Server 12.0.4 and work in tandem with gitlab. Ubuntu itself is a virtual machine in Hyper-V Server 2012 R2.

I'm comparing performance of command `git clone git@my-server:group/repo.git`, so it is not a 'local git' protocol, but always SSH.

If I clone via ssh from same VM - it shows speed ~15-20 MiB/s. From other VM on the same physical server or from other machine in the same LAN - 70-200 KiB/s, which is painfully slow. I have tried both windows boxes and linux ones.

I tried to google and found [this](http://darrell.mozingo.net/2011/09/29/painfully-slow-clone-speeds-with-msysgit-gitextensions/) one, but it seems not an issue: I've tried a) to use Putty's PLink; b) update OpenSSH to Jan 2014 version on windows or even c) use linux box - with no luck.

I've tried to use iperf and it is definitely not a problem of the network: connection between VMs in the same hypervisor is ~300-400 Mb/s, between VM and other machine in LAN - ~10 Mb/s (100 Mbit ethernet connection).

So, my question is - how I can find where is the bottleneck? I'm out of ideas right now.

P.S. It's not SSH issue probably - cloning via http shows nearly same speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that you can clone at 15 MBs from the gitlab VM makes this most likely a problem with the network abstraction layer of the hypervisor.

---

- Test if all network connections are slow by sending [raw data](http://jbowes.wordpress.com/2010/10/13/measuring-network-speeds-with-netcat-and-dd/) between 2 linux VMs.

  On secondary linux VM run:

  ```
  nc -v -l -p 4321 > /dev/null
  ```

  On the gitlab VM run:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024K count=512 | nc -v $IP_OF_FIRST_MACHINE -p 4321
  ```

  This will show your network speed. Most likely this will be [slow](http://systemscentre.blogspot.com/2013/12/network-speed-issues-in-windows-server.html)
- [Turn off VMQ](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/999f218d-e8f9-42de-ab82-3d22bd5b67e9/hyperv-and-very-slow-network?forum=winserverhyperv) on the hypervisor
- Try [turning off jumbo frames](http://blogs.technet.com/b/cedward/archive/2011/05/05/hyper-v-networking-optimizations-part-4-of-6-jumbo-frames.aspx) (MTU > 1500)
- Lastly, try doing a tcp dump from wireshark inside of the gitlab vm. See if there are errors that jump out

Comment: Turning off VMQ made my day, thanks a lot! In case someone needs it, PS command is here: `Get-NetAdapter -Physical | Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty | Where-Object "RegistryKeyword" -EQ "*VMQ" | Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -DisplayValue "Disabled"`

Comment: nc command requires a '-p' to listen on a certain port

Comment: Turning off VMQ speed up my network around 200x.

Answer (score 3):

Check your DNS settings/servers. I had this issue and found out it was caused by my primary dns not resolving the git server. Once I switched my primary it sped up. Appears that git doesn't allow caching of DNS queries and therefore had to failover every time.

Comment: Just have tried cloning via IP (`git clone git@a.b.c.d:group/repo.git`) - no better, unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried performance monitoring on the git server? Is your git server providing any other services? What are the specs on the git VM?

Comment: @ Craneum, yes, there's plenty of disk space available (~100 Gb while ~10 Gb used), CPU utilization never spiked over dozen of percent and average memory usage is ~25% of available 4 Gb.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is a most perplexing problem. Do you have [bandwidth limits](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/set-bandwidth-limits-for-hyper-v-vms-with-windows-server-2012/) set on your virtual NIC port? If you do... that might be it...

Just posting this because you didn't mention it in your OP and it's possible it could be an answer, but I don't know for sure if this will be it.

Comment: Nope. Anyway, then iperf would have shown the same slow numbers, which is not the case.